# How can I use jQuery to push JSON data into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm new to jQuery, and I'm trying out the `getJSON` function. What I want to do is pull the "id" section of a JSON file and push it into an array called `planes` in jQuery. From there, the array is used in an autocomplete function to fill in the searchable IDs.

```
var planes = [];
$.getJSON('planes.json', function(data) {
    console.log('Filling array...');

//This is where I think the issue is occurring. 
//Is using the name of the section you want to use the correct syntax here?
    $.each(data.id, function (index, val) {
        planes.push(val.id);
        console.log('Pushed ' + index);
    });
});

// After getJSON, array should look something like this:
// var planes = [
//  'Alara',
//  'Fiora',
//  'Innistrad',
//  'Kamigawa',
//  'Lorwyn',
//  'Mirrodin',
//  'Ravnica',
//  'Shandalar',
//  'Zendikar'
// ];
```

The JSON file is arranged like so:

```
[ 
    {"id": "Ravnica"},
    {"id": "Lorwyn"},
    {"id": "Innistrad"},
    {"id": "Zendikar"},
    {"id": "Kamigawa"},
    {"id": "Mirrodin"},
    {"id": "Shandalar"},
    {"id": "Alara"},
    {"id": "Fiora"}
]
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/EDLzeF1aFfEmjskLiBAD)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Btw, are you using mtgjson.com's dataset? If not, that could save you a lot of time for whatever your project is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it, although you are looping through `data.id` which is not what you want to be doing. You should just loop through `data`, and push `val.id`.

If you *wanted* to loop through `data.id`, then you're json would have to be structured like so:

```
{
    "id": [
        "things",
        "to",
        "loop",
        "through"
    ]
}
```

..but it's not, so just loop through data.

Comment: This was it! Thanks for your help. In addition, it looks like I could have structured my JSON differently to make this a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following solution. I have hard coded plane data instead of getting from file but solution is same. You just need update your $.each line by iterating over data instead of data.id (this is you'r bug rest of code is fine).

```js
var data = [{
  "id": "Ravnica"
}, {
  "id": "Lorwyn"
}, {
  "id": "Innistrad"
}, {
  "id": "Zendikar"
}, {
  "id": "Kamigawa"
}, {
  "id": "Mirrodin"
}, {
  "id": "Shandalar"
}, {
  "id": "Alara"
}, {
  "id": "Fiora"
}];
var planes = [];
//surround this each with your $.getJSON. I have just hardcoded json data instead of getting it from file
$.each(data, function(index, val) {
  planes.push(val.id);
});

console.log(planes);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Your update plunker link [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ePnQW8QB5riCHDRJfbBN?p=info)

Answer (score 0):

You might also look into the native array map method, which saves you having to create an array and then push things onto it. It just returns a new array given the original array by applying the mapping function on each item.

```
$.getJSON("planes.json",function(data){
    console.log(data.map(function(plane){return plane.id;}))
}
```

However, this is not available in IE<=8 if I recall correctly.